# concatenate values and delete the remaining rows using arrays

Tags: performance, array, vba, excel

the below code used to:
Concatenate the values on a specific column "**N**" depend on the value of column "**A**" then delete the remaining rows.

It works, but with range of 30k rows the macro takes a long time to finish (14 seconds) on powerful PC.

**Edit:**
the bottle neck is on this line   `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).EntireRow.Delete`
(**it takes 13.5 seconds**) from the overall code time ( 14 seconds).
I tried to replace it with VBA `AutoFilter` , but the same issue.

**This is updated screenshot:** of current values and the current result,

[image]

My goal is to do all processing on arrays or dictionary to achieve the fastest speed.
I have office 2016 on my work.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub Concatenate_column_N_values_Delete_remaining_Rows()

    Dim t: t = Timer

    Const sep As String = vbLf
    
    Dim arrKeys, arrVals, arrFlags, rngRows As Range, key, currKey, s As String
    Dim ub As Long, n As Long, ws As Worksheet, rngVals As Range, i As Long
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rngRows = ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)   'Column Contains WO
    Set rngVals = rngRows.EntireRow.Columns("N")     'Column contains pure string
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    arrKeys = rngRows.Value2
    ub = UBound(arrKeys, 1)
    arrVals = rngVals.Value2
    ReDim arrFlags(1 To UBound(arrKeys, 1), 1 To 1)
 
    currKey = Chr(0)     'non-existing key...
    For i = ub To 1 Step -1                      'looping from bottom up
        key = arrKeys(i, 1)                      'this row's key
        If key <> currKey Then                   'different key from row below?
            If i < ub Then arrVals(i + 1, 1) = s 'populate the collected info for any previous key
            s = arrVals(i, 1)                    'collect this row's "N" value
            currKey = key                        'set as current key
        Else
            If i < ub Then
                arrFlags(i + 1, 1) = "x" 'flag for deletion
                n = n + 1
            End If
            s = arrVals(i, 1) & sep & s             'concatenate the "N" value
        End If
    Next i
    arrVals(1, 1) = s                              'populate the last (first) row...
    rngVals.Value = arrVals                        'drop the concatenated values
    
    If n > 0 Then    'any rows to delete?
        With rngRows.Offset(0, 100) 'use any empty column
            .Value = arrFlags
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).EntireRow.Delete
        End With
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    Debug.Print "Concatenate_column_N_values_Delete_remaining_Rows, in " & Round(Timer - t, 2) & " sec"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You can do this almost instantly with powerquery groupby https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/group-by. Alternatively using the new array helper functions UNIQUE & BYROW should be pretty speedy for that amount of data (not that I've got anything against VBA, I just don't think it's great for data manipulation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The Bottle Neck:

the bottle neck is on this line `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).EntireRow.Delete`
(it takes **13.5** seconds) from the code overall time ( 14 seconds).

#### Reason:

It is tuned out that deletion of a lot of non-continuous rows takes a lot of time to finish, even after using Application optimizations (`ScreenUpdateing.False`,...)

#### Answer:

I tried another approach by sort the values (rows) which need to be deleted and then set this rows to a range and then delete that range ,
I measured (**Sorting values + Deletion of that range**) and it toke **0.12 sec** to finish (significantly faster).

I replaced `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).EntireRow.Delete` with the below code.

```
Sub Sort_vlaues_x_and_Delete()

    Dim ws As Worksheet:   Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim rng As Range, lastR As Long, lastC As Long, lastcol As String
 
     lastR = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row                    'Last Row number on coulmn A
      lastC = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1       'next Last Column on Row 1
       lastcol = Split(Cells(1, lastC).Address(True, False), "$")(0)       'Last Column Letter

    Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lastR, lastC))
    
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
'--- Sort values x

    ws.Sort.SortFields.Clear
     ws.Sort.SortFields.Add key:=Range(lastcol & "2:" & lastcol & lastR), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
       With ws.Sort
          .SetRange Range("A1:" & lastcol & lastR)
          .Header = xlYes: .MatchCase = False
          .Orientation = xlTopToBottom: .SortMethod = xlPinYin
          .Apply
       End With
       
'--- Delete range of values x

    lastR = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, lastcol).End(xlUp).Row
     Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(lastR, lastC))
       rng.Rows.EntireRow.Delete
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, in Excel 2016 [you should have access](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2015/09/10/integrating-power-query-technology-in-excel-2016/) to the Power Query Editor through `Data` tab -> `From Table/Range`

Then combining the text as you have done and loading to a new table should be easy - ***this is the entire code:***

```
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Concat = Table.Group(Source, {"WO"}, {{"TEXT", each Text.Combine([TEXT]," "), type text}})
```

The first line loads "Table1" from your workbook. The second line `Group`s the table rows based on `{"WO"}` column, and aggregates `each` group of rows using the `Text.Combine` function on the `[TEXT]` column of the table, with spaces as separators.

---

To generate that you follow these steps:

- Click inside the table with the data
- `Data Tab -> From Table/Range` to launch PowerQuery (PQ)
- `Home -> GroupBy`
- Choose the WO column in the first dropdown, and for the aggregation function choose anything, we'll overwrite this
- Click okay and now in the formula bar you should see `= Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"WO"} ...`, replace that with `= Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"WO"}, {{"TEXT", each Text.Combine([TEXT]," "), type text}})`. Hit enter

  - *Optional* - In the steps pane on the right you can right click delete the `Changed Type` step as it is not really needed. You can also rename the steps.
- Now in the top left hit the close and load  icon and your PQ will load to a new tab by default. Every time your source data changes, go `Data -> Refresh All` to re-run the PQ.

  - *Optional* -  You can use the dropdown under the save icon to `Close and Load To` a different location, e.g. a table next to the source data

[image: final result]

---

#### Justification

Like VBA

- It is built into Excel and the powerquery travels embedded in your workbook so you won't lose it
- It can dynamically switch to pulling data from different sources

This is an improvement over VBA because

- It is simpler (much less code) and easier to understand, adjust and modify as a result
- It should be very fast, powerquery can run multithreaded and generally is optimised for data manipulation
- You will find it supports built in features VBA does not, if you want to build on this data manipulation in future
- The editor for powerquery is graphical - so you don't type the code but instead click buttons to insert it for you, making it simpler to learn and less error prone

---

#### Update

To join with newlines use `Text.Combine([TEXT],"#(cr)#(lf)")` instead of `Text.Combine([TEXT]," ")`, or use `Lines.ToText([TEXT])` but this adds a trailing newline.

Comment: I tried, but I got a space between each text and I need each text to be on a new line like my provided photo. I replaced `" "` with `vbCrLf` but it did not work   , `= Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"WO"}, {{"Urlname", each Text.Combine([Urlname], vbCrLf), type text}})`

Comment: @Leedo sorry different spot that. You can use `Lines.ToText([Urlname])` or `Text.Combine([Urlname], "#(lf)")` instead I believe https://stackoverflow.com/q/63959297/6609896

Comment: @Leedo see update. please let me know the performance

Comment: I tried and it works, up-voted.